# what causes water to be white in a river?

Tags: optics, water, air

I know it is because of turbulance, causing air to enter the water. But neither air nor water are White, why does the combination of the two make White.

Comment: Are you talking about *foam*?

Comment: It's not just water and air but also surfactants.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77516/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sunlight, made up of a mixture of all colors,  scatters when it passes between materials, each with a different refractive index, in this case water and air.  The water in the river only meets the air at one surface, but the droplets in the air/water  mixture contains millions of surfaces.  This combination scatters the light more so it appears white overall, as do the tops of breaking waves at sea.