# Why is snow white when water has no color?

Tags: thermodynamics, optics, geometric-optics, weather

I just don't get it. Isn't snow just another form of water? Also are all ices transparent or do they go white after a certain temperature?

Comment: Glass is just another form of silicon dioxide, and yet it's transparent while sand isn't. Ice is just a form of water, but you can swim in water, while not in ice. Form is important :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are so many different types of objects white, yet appear gray when they are wet?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77516/)

Comment: Regarding the title, [water does have a color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_of_water).

Comment: Snow is white _because_ water has (almost) no colour.

Comment: Analogous question on Chem. SE http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/26749/

Comment: **the answers here** answer this question much better than the answers there, I think this should have been left open so that it doesn't redirect readers to the other answers. Linking to this question currently auto-bumps people elsewhere.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That's same for cloud, fog, wave splash and so on.  Because of tiny size (but  in large number) and irregular appearance, reflection and refraction occur in an irregular manner so the light is scattered randomly so that every images and colors mixed together.  As a result, it looks white.  By the way, under thick clouds, they look dark because all the light from the top has scattered away.  Under microscope, snow flakes (ice crystal aggregate in fractal way) look crystal clear.

[image]

Photo credit goes to ***Henry David Thoreau***:

1. [**snowcrystals.com**](http://snowcrystals.com)
2. [**photos' link**](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~atomic/snowcrystals/kids/samplecrystals.jpg)
3. **Method of illumination** is mentioned at the end of [**this link**](http://www.snowcrystals.com/white/white.html).

Comment: Given this, could a group of snowflakes cause enough create a rainbow? :D

Comment: @Anoplexian No, rainbows rely on the relative uniformity of the liquid drops to scatter light consistently across the curcular arcs of relative angle to the sun and viewer.  But small ice crystals can create a [similar effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_iridescence).

Comment: It should be noted that, because they scatter light, they only look white when most of the light hitting them is white. If the sky were red the snow would look red as well.

Comment: @Dave This property is true of most things that we attribute a color to. A white wall will also only appear white if the light hitting the wall is mostly white. It is also not the color of the sky that determines the color of the clouds. The clear sky is blue (due to Rayleigh scattering), but the clouds are still white because the direct sun light is white.

Comment: @Anoplexian: Not a rainbow, but you can get conditions (large crystaline flakes on top of snow cover) that produces lots of diamond-like reflections/refractions in the sunlight.

Comment: @jkej Good point. When we speak about what color something is, we typically mean "what color does it appear when illuminated with white light?" In this case, the snow appears white.

Comment: @Anoplexian I suspect the slight rainbowish hues you can see in these photos is owing to the wavelength dependence of the Fresnel equations describing the angled facets of the crystals, and the fact that different facets present different angles. There is probably some Fabry-Perot etalon effects and maybe even stress birefringence effects (the lighting for these micrographs is probably polarized).

Comment: Dear all: Photo credit is updated in my answer, please feel free to see the link for *"method of illumination"* at the bottom.  Many thanks to all of your responses.

Answer (score 17):

Snow is simply a random collection of snowflakes and bits of irregularly shapen bits of ice. Each of these is clear, but a small fraction of the light incident on each clear entity is reflected and scattered. The fraction is of the order of 2%.

Light passing through snow encounters huge numbers of these randomly oriented interfaces. So a large fraction of it is scattered. The wavefronts of the incident waves are completely randomized by this scattering, so the scattering can no longer form images. The same goes for any light that passes through the snow: its wavefront is highly randomized and cannot form images.

The scattering happens roughly equally to all visible wavelengths, which is why we see white, diffuse light from snow when it is lit by a broadband source like the Sun.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't white. You perceive it to be white because it is clear and it is reflecting the full spectrum of light applied to it.

As for why snow appears white and, say, raindrops do not, the answer lies in the crystalline and faceted nature of snow. Consider a clear ice cube which, when crushed, appears white.

Comment: Isn't anything that reflects the full spectrum considered as white?

Comment: When it is reflecting the full spectrum, it can be. If you shine a red (or any other color) light at it, no.

Comment: Isn't that what "white" _means_? In other words, are there any white things whose whiteness is not for exactly this reason?

Comment: @HenningMakholm you could have something that just emits (through reflection, or as a direct source) just red, green and blue, in order to stimulate the rods in your eye to make you believe you are seeing white.  In fact, you are looking at a device that does that, _right now_

Comment: @Baldrickk: Sure, but I'm not sure I would say that device "is white" itself.

Comment: @HenningMakholm true. Though 'white' often isn't; the light spectra isn't necessarilly uniform.  See https://cdn.comsol.com/wordpress/2016/01/Combined-plot-of-emission-spectra.png from https://www.comsol.com/blogs/calculating-the-emission-spectra-from-common-light-sources/ for an example. Our brains are quite good at doing "white balance" like cameras do. Try wearing rose tinted glasses for a bit, and then noticing how everything looke blue when you take them off.  Usually, when we talk about colours, we are usually referring to how we observe them.  (looking at the full spectra is also valid)

Comment: @Baldrickk: I don't think that is relevant for when a thing is white. A white object is one that reflects the ambient illumination _at whatever spectrum that ambient illumination has_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes indeed.  I was noting that something that something that just reflects Red, Green and Blue is indistinguishable (to us at least) from something that is "true" white, as it will behave the same under the same light source.  In terms of "white" being uniform reflectiveness/emittance, then it doesn't meet the criteria, in terms of "white" being indistinguishable from the above, then no.  Depending on the definition of "white" chosen, the answer can be either. If you just want the colour as we see it, then the answer to your question is "yes" (RGB sources)

Comment: @Baldrickk: At best that would produce a _grey_ object that _appears_ white when viewed under a particular jagged-spectrum illumination. (And under a light with peaks elsewhere in the spectrum it might appear to be black).

Comment: @Baldrikk Your point is sort of technically valid, but also kind of irrelevant. An object that reflects all wavelengths roughly equally (and relatively highly) is the type of thing that is typically called white. The type of object that you are describing (only reflecting specific bands of RGB) would be highly exotic and human made precisely for this purpose. Should this object be described as white? Maybe. It will appear white in ordinary white light, but I could construct other "white" light sources in which your object would not appear white.